# Статичные файлы для шаблона с gorillamux

Tags: golang

Есть роутинги:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/", home)
r.HandleFunc("/a", home)
r.HandleFunc("/a/b", home)
r.HandleFunc("/a/b/c", home)
```

Подключаю статики:

```
r.PathPrefix("/css/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/css/",http.FileServer(http.Dir("./tmpl/css/"))))
http.Handle("/", r)
```

Home:

```
t := template.New("index.html")
t, _ = t.ParseFiles("./tmpl/index.html")
err := t.Execute(w, nil)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprint(w, err)
    return
}
```

`.html` и `.css` это один див и стиль к нему

Т.е. когда я захожу на `localhost/a` то стили определяются как `localhost/css/` и отрабатывают, как только захожу на `localhost/a/b` стили уже в `localhost/a/css/` и не отрабатывают.

Как с этим бороться?

Comment: Не ясно что нужно. Для каждого пути свой путь к стилям или для всех путей - один путь к стилям. Мне кажется что проблема не в роутере а в шаблоне. Как так оказывается, что стили в `/a/css/...`? Но если так - то кто их будет обрабатывать? Хендлер же только для `/css/...`.

Comment: Нужно для всех путей один путь к стилям. Как оказывается, что стили в `/a/css/` я не знаю. стили подключаю вот так `<link href="css/css.css" ... />`

Comment: Воспроизвести не удалось [паста](http://pastebin.com/EAGYV7x9). Может стоит обновить гориллу? У меня go1.5.1. Гориллу ставил месяц назад примерно. А может дело в других компонентах Вашего кода. Смотрите пасту.

Comment: Есть ещё вариант, что дело не в том  и не в другом. В том случае, если трафик идёт через какой-нибудь прокси, который перезаписывает пути.

Comment: А ещё один момент `href=/css/css.css`, а не `href=css/css.css`. Может дело в этом.

Comment: да, изменил сейчас с `href=css/css.css` на `href=/css/css.css` и успех.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё дело в пути к стилям. Если он начинается не со слэша `/`, то путь относителен. В случае с `/a/b` путь будет относительно `/a`, т.е. `/a/css/css.css`. Для `/a` путь относителен `/`, поэтому работает нормально. Просто добавьте `/` к пути так: `href="/css/css.css"`.